# Shading issues after normals baking

Tags: shaders, normals, baking

a). I baked normal map and applyed it to lowpoly mesh and I made 3 clones of it with different options for demonstration purposes
b). I got the issue with shading
What I want to be: lowpoly mesh without additional geometry and with correct shading and smooth
At the screenshot you can see (from right to left):
1.highpoly mesh that I baked from
2.smoothed lowpoly mesh with additional geometry I want to reduce, but it has correct shading and smoothing
3, 4 and the second screenshot. lowpoly meshes that I want to produce, but with correct shading and smoothing
So how can I do this?
[image: screenshot_1]
[image: screenshot_2]
[blend_file](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/zKH71XKGQDvq0Q)

Comment: See [How to upload an image 
to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491).

Answer (score 0):

To fix to shading in Blender, select the 2nd object in Object mode ...

- go to *Object Data Properties* tab

  - expand ► *Normals*, and activate **☑** *Auto Smooth*, `30°`
  - expand ► *Geometry Data*, and clear the <kbd>x Custom Split Normals Data</kbd>
- go to *Modifiers* tab

  - remove the *WeightedNormals* modifier